# Upload document to SharePoint from External Application

Tags: rest

I have an external application where we want to show a upload form where documents uploaded should go in SharePoint Document library in the backend. Is there any REST api that can do this job for us?

Please guide!. any other option to do it?

Comment: Documents can also be emailed as attachments to Document Library.

Comment: can you just tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery & REST API combined to upload a file to SharePoint online.

Below is the best example explained on MSDN:-

[Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx)

[Upload file to Sharepoint from External MVC Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976171/upload-file-to-sharepoint-from-external-mvc-web-application)

Please let me know if you do have any query in it.

Comment: Have you got it working?

Comment: the options you are giving will not work on non sharepoint project. i want something that will work on non sharepoint

Comment: It will work only on non SharePoint project ... Please check the links in answer

Comment: is that works for you? Please check second link if not.

Comment: first link is for sharepoint application only as it can be written only in sharepoint apps. Second link might work but i am looking something in javascript

Comment: Dude both works for external application

Comment: I had tried both....

Comment: How first link works for you in non sharePoint project? it has appWebUrl and hostWebUrl

Comment: Have you got it working?

Comment: yes but i used webservice copy.asmx instead in javascript

Comment: Given links are also working as i tried them in my test environment. That's why i asked you.

Comment: BTW you asked for REST API solution so i gave it. If you asked for JS than also i can give the solution

Comment: first link dint work for me. second i dint try. anyways thanks. i will upvote your answer for the help

Comment: In case if you need than you can use it in future as i tested both. that's the only thing i want to let you know. Thanks BTW

Comment: @Hardik What is the JS solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can email attachments to a document library.

First incoming email has to be configured on the server. Search for instructions specific to what year you're on. Second, go to Library settings for the library where you want the documents. Click "Incoming e-mail settings" and select Yes, add email address, select "Save all attachments in root folder," set "save original email" to No. The security policy will depend on whether you're sending from a SharePoint account with permissions to the library.